# regular expression in django blogs.html file error

Tags: python, html, django, url, expression

Can anyone trouble shoot the error in the following code:

**Code:** (in the blog.html file, that is in the blog app)

```
1   {% extends "aboutme/header.html" %}
2   
3   {%block content %}
4       {% for post in object_list %}
5           <h5>{{post.date|date:Y-m-d"}}<a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></h5>
6       {% end for %}
7   {% endblock %}
```

**Error on running: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/**

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/
Could not parse the remainder: '-m-d"' from 'post.date|date:Y-m-d"'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '-m-d"' from 'post.date|date:Y-m-d"'
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in __init__, line 668
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\pythonsite\\mysite',
 'C:\\windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 13 Dec 2017 19:13:00 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\User\Desktop\pythonsite\mysite\blog\templates\blog\blog.html, error at line 5
Could not parse the remainder: '-m-d"' from 'post.date|date:Y-m-d"'
1   {% extends "aboutme/header.html" %}
2   
3   {%block content %}
4       {% for post in object_list %}
5           <h5>{{post.date|date:Y-m-d"}}<a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></h5>
6       {% end for %}
7   {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is `TemplateSyntaxError`. your missing double quote in `date:"Y-m-d"` .so when the django template processor try to parse the template it could not find the opening of first double quote

```
{% extends "aboutme/header.html" %}
    2   
    3   {%block content %}
    4       {% for post in object_list %}
    5           <h5>{{post.date|date:"Y-m-d"}}<a href="/blog/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a></h5>
    6       {% end for %}
    7   {% endblock %}
```

as it's clearly state in error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/
Could not parse the remainder: '-m-d"' from 'post.date|date:Y-m-d"'
```